# Manage Guardians of Classroom Api .

Tags: google-classroom

I am using manage guardians of classroom api and I am getting error : AttributeError: 'Resource' object has no attribute 'userProfiles'

```
  invitations = self.service.userProfiles().guardianInvitations().list(studentId='esha.dammalapati@somedomain.com').execute()
```

Comment: Can you try in this [Try-it](https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/userProfiles/get) if your email is valid? Also post more code.

Comment: Yeah got it working . It was an issue with email address .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to close this issue. Make sure you're using a valid e-mail address because that's where userProfile refers to.

You can check if you're using a valid email address in [userProfiles.get Try-it](https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/userProfiles/get).